# Uniform boundedness and boundedness of Maclaurin coefficients

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose $f(z)$ is a bounded in some region $|z|\leq R>1 $ and analytic function and consider the Maclaurin series for $f$:
$$  f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n.$$ My question is:

1. What are the conditions on $f$ for $f^{(n)}(0)$ to be uniformly  bounded?
2. Do the uniform bounds for $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ exist without further   conditions  on
   $f$?

   3.If $a_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}\frac{f^j(0)}{j!}$,what  can we say about the convergence or boundedness of the partial sums of the series of $\sum_0^{\infty} a_j.$

The parts (1) and (2) seem too nontrial to me and for (3) I conjecture based on numerical evidence that it should be bounded at least. I would also like to know whether my following exploration is correct.
**Convegence of $\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$** 
For $f $ as given we have the Mclaurin series for $f$ is given by
$$  f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
Since $f$ f is analytic and bounded  in $|z| \leq 1$  , we have :
$$ f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$
As f is analytic and  $f(1)$
is bounded this means the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ is convergent  to $f(1)$ and hence the series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}| $$ must be bounded   which requires  $$|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}| \rightarrow 0$$ as $n$ goes to infinity?
Is the above conclusion valid for a bounded analytic function?

I will be highly obliged for any clarifications/hints!

Comment: For (3) consider $f(z)=1/(1-z)$.  This question is not a research-level problem and so is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: I posted  it on mathstackexcahge previously and somebody said asking for the necessary and sufficient conditions for 1 and 2 is to ask too much